# Read something from website in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hello i want to ask something ... Is there a way to read some information from website that i do not own from a code behind

Like i want to read title of every page in some web site ... Can i do it and how ?

Not a way of hacking just to read  the clear text no html code want to read

I don't know what to do or how to do it i need an ideas

And is there a way to search for specific word in several website and an api to use it for search for a website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still have to read the HTML since that's how the title is transmitted.

Use the [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to make a request to the web server and the [HttpWebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the response back and the GetResponseStream() method to the response. Then you need to parse it in some way.

Look at the [HTMLAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) in order to parse the HTML. You can use this to get the title element out of the HTML and read it. You can then get all the anchor  elements within the page and determine which ones you want to visit next that are on their site to scan the titles.

Answer (score 0):

There is powerful HTML parser available for .Net that you can use with XPATH to read HTML pages,
[HTML Agility pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Or

you can use built in `WebClient` class to get data from page as string and then do string manipulation.